# Get the songs from this array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am having issues apparently. I have been reading [Foreach Loops Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and apparently in one loop I need all the songs from an array such as this:

```
$music = array(
    'Creed' => array(
        'Human Clay' => array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Are You Ready'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'What If'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Beautiful'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Say I'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Wrong Way'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Faceless Man'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Never Die'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'With Arms Wide pen'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Higher'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Was Away Those Years'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Inside Us All'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Track 12'
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

What I have so far is:

```
foreach($music['Creed']['Human Clay'] as $song){
   var_dump($song);
}
```

the problem is, $song is an array. I have to do this in one loop. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes!

```
foreach($music['Creed']['Human Clay'] as $song){
   echo $song['title'];
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rek-bcn

Comment: I knew I was missing something basic >.< thank you. Will accept in 11 minutes

Comment: Sorry I forgot about it >.< but I accepted it :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive) in case for example you don't know how deep each section goes:

```
$songs = [];    
array_walk_recursive($music, function($v) use (&$songs) {$songs[] = $v;});
print_r($songs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSongsList($arr, $album){
 $length = count($arr['Creed'][$album]);
 $result = array();
 for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
  $result[$i] = $arr['Creed'][$album][$i]['title'];
 }
 return $result;
}

//Usage

print_r(getSongsList($music, 'Human Clay'));
```